# Error con push en laravel - Call to a member function push() on integer

Tags: php, laravel, colecciones

Tengo el siguiente fragmento de codigo:

```
        $usuarios = collect();
        temp_historico_sede::chunk(1000, function ($establecimientos, $usuarios) 
        {
            foreach ($establecimientos as $establecimiento) {
                if (Riesgos::where('codigo_dane', $establecimiento->codigo_sede)->exists()){
                    $usuarios->push(['Sede' => $establecimiento->nombre_sede]);
                }
            }
        });
```

Por algún motivo la variable usuarios pasa como un integer en vez de como una colección, no tengo idea de porque esta pasando esto, agradecería los comentarios para identificar el problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al helper `collect()` no le estás mandando nada como parámetro, primero crea el array con formato "llave => valor" y ya después lo conviertes a colección, tu código quedaría así:

```
    $usuarios = array();
    temp_historico_sede::chunk(1000, function ($establecimientos) use(&$usuarios) 
    {
        foreach ($establecimientos as $establecimiento) {
            if (Riesgos::where('codigo_dane', $establecimiento->codigo_sede)->exists()){
                $usuarios[] = ['Sede' => $establecimiento->nombre_sede];

            }
        }
    });

    $coleccion_usuarios = collect($usuarios);
```

Comment: Sigue el problema, ahora me da este error.

"Cannot use a scalar value as an array"

Comment: @DaNiEl Ya edité mi respuesta, la función callback de `chunk` no recibe "n" parámetros, solo recibe el parámetro del modelo al que le quieres aplicar eso, si necesitas usar una variable ajena a la función debes mandársela mediante `use()` y le coloqué el `&` ya que el valor necesitamos que persista después de que esa función termine de ejecutarse y cambie su valor.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, funciona perfecto :^)